# System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration in System.Linq.Expressions method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

Mates, I am trying to build a expression tree using System.Linq.Expressions and I am getting this error:

> Erro: System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration
>        at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters)
>        at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body,
>   String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>        at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body,
>   Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>        at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body,
>   ParameterExpression[] parameters)
>        at Gedi.Controllers.OperacaoController.opBuscaFile(FormCollection form) in c:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Gedi\Gedi\Controllers\OperacaoController.cs:line 338

**The code:**

```
IQueryable<String> queryableData = AllIndexValues.AsQueryable<string>();


//docTypeId == idTipo
ParameterExpression pe1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "docTypeId");
Expression right = Expression.Constant(idTipo);
Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(pe1, right);


//idIndice == 16
ParameterExpression pe2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "idIndice");
right = Expression.Constant(16, typeof(int));
Expression e2 = Expression.Equal(pe2, right);

//docTypeId == idTipo AND idIndice == 16
Expression predicateBody = Expression.And(e1,e2);

//queryableData.Where(docTypeId => (docTypeId ==  idTipo) AND idIndice => (idIndice ==  16)) 
MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where", new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType }, queryableData.Expression, Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(predicateBody, new ParameterExpression[] { pe1, pe2 }));

IQueryable<string> results = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<string (whereCallExpression);

return Content(""+results);
```

I have adapted this code from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637.aspx

Thanks

Comment: which line is 338? You're supplying the wrong number of parameters there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the initial problem, I think:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(predicateBody,
                                      new ParameterExpression[] { pe1, pe2 }))
```

A `Func<string, bool>` takes just a `string` and returns a `bool`. So it only has a single parameter. You're passing in *two* `ParameterExpressions`. Also, they're *both* `int` parameters... not a string in sight!

So you could use:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int, bool>>(predicateBody,
                                        new ParameterExpression[] { pe1, pe2 }))
```

... but my guess is that's not going to help you, if you want a `Where` clause...

Given this comment:

```
//queryableData.Where(docTypeId => (docTypeId ==  idTipo) AND idIndice => (idIndice ==  16))
```

... it sounds like you're confused even before we get to expression trees. You can't combine two lambda expressions like that.

I strongly advise you to work out what your code would look like if you *didn't* need to build expression trees, and then convert it. What is the element type of `queryableData`? You're only going to get one value per predicate test - is that going to be a `docTypeId` or an `idIndice`?

Comment: thanks. What I need is do build a where clause dinamically. I have to pass a unknown numbers of predicates based on a search form. I have for example 3 field and the user might use just 2 as a criteria. Or sometimes I have 5 fields and I could use all of then. I have no ideia how to proceed.

Comment: @DimasLongo: But you'll only get *one* value in the `Where` clause itself. It would be more reasonable for you to build the equivalent of `queryableData.Where(x => x.DocTypeId == idTipo && x.IdIndice == 16)` for example... at which point you have *one* parameter, but you use property expressions to extract different bits from the entity.

Comment: Based on that would be possible to queryableData.Where(x => x.DocTypeId == idTipo && (x.IdIndice == 16 && x.IdIndice.value == 'value') ).. I have diferent idIndice.. for instance for idIndice == 16 check for value x and for idIndice == 17 check for value y

Comment: @DimasLongo: I'm afraid I don't really understand your comments - but it's not clear that you've taken on board my main point - that you should be working on the basis of a *single* parameter.